# Ubuntu 23.04 login screen is blank after changes in graphics

Tags: 22.04

Ubuntu 23.04 was working fine, I was trying to install nvidia drivers and made some changes in xserver, gdm and lighttdm. After that, it doesnt show my login screen, its just blacn.